# making my own jquery pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination

I've made my own jquery pagination where when you press the page button, the current page disappears and then the page , which corresponds to the button number, fades in. The problem is that page 2 appears but a little lower than where page 1 appears and page 3 is even lower than where page 1 was. Every page that appears is supposed to be at the same position where page 1 starts out at.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMwWh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a `<br>` between the page elements.

This break tag adds extra space above your pages.

Between page 1 and 2 there is one `<br>`, So page 2 has 1 empty line above it.
Between page 1 and 3 there are two `<br>`'s and so there are 2 empty lines above page 3.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have too many breaks.

compare the beginning of page 1

```
    <div id="page1" class="page">
           <li id="panel">
```

with that of page 2

```
       </li></div><br><div id="page2" class="page"><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove BRs between "page" elements as well as the ones that are inside the page elements.

Answer (score 0):

The guys above are right but, when I do mine, I just position with css. To me, this is a stylesheet problem. Lose the breaks.